# Django: accessing model attributes

Tags: python, django, django-models

Apologies for the noobish question, I am completely new to both Python and Django and trying to make my first app.

I have a simple class

```
class About(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField('date added')
```

to which I've added a single record.  I can access this with

```
about = About.objects.filter(id=1)
```

however, if I try to use dot syntax to access its attributes I get the following error

```
    >>> about.title
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'title'
```

I know how to use unicode in the model to specify a nicer return value such as

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title
```

should I be using this to format the model data into a dictionary/list?  Or am I just completely missing some default behaviour?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your case, `about` is a [QuerySet object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/), not an instance of your model. Try

```
print about[0].title
```

Alternatively, use [get() to retrieve a single instance of the model](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get):

```
about = About.objects.get(id=1)
print about.title
```

Comment: I am also asking a naive question.
Why do we have it like Model.objects.get() or Model.objects.all() like this
and not directly Model.get() or Model.all()
What does we achieve with using objects ?

Comment: @user - 'objects' is the name of what we call a 'Manager' and it's the mechanism by which you interface with Django models. 'Objects' is the default name, but you can override it however you like, or write your own managers too, if you want. Lots of info in the docs on managers, take a look :)

Answer (score 2):

Filter returns a QuerySet and not the single object you are looking for. Use get instead of filter.

Methods that return new QuerySets

- filter
- ...

Methods that do not return QuerySets

- get
- ...

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) explains, `filter` *always* returns a QuerySet, which is a list-like collection of items, even if only one element matches the filter condition. So you can slice the list to access your element - `about[0]` - or, better, use `get()` instead:

```
about = About.objects.get(id=1)
print about.title
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want get just one row

```
about = About.objects.get(pk=1)
```

now `about` is an object(one row)

`filter` returns list, so for accessing items in list you must use `index`(about[0]) or `for loop`.but `get` return exactly one row.